# Mapping/Observable object with ajax

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I used the following ajax code to obtain an object called Client by it's id like so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "api/client/GetClient/" + id,
            contentType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                model.selectedClient(result);
                $("#loader").hide();
            },
            failure: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
                $("#loader").hide();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("An error occurred, please try again.");
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
        });
```

But although the selectedClient is an observable its values aren't so if I bind the value of say selectedClient().Name to a textbox, changing the textbox doesn't update the value.  I don't want to create a function and a push method, I like being able to simply put the returned object in so future changes are seamless.  What can I do to make them observable values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedClient` should be observable and so does it's properties if you want to reflect the changes in UI.

How are you creating your selectedClient?

You should actually create a class like this:

```
Client = function(data){
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{},this);
}
```

have a property in your viewmodel like this:

```
selectedClient = ko.observable()
```

and your success method of ajax should be:

```
success: function (result) {
            model.selectedClient(new Client (result));
            $("#loader").hide();
         }
```

This will make sure whenever your object's properties changes, your view reflects it. For more information, you can refer this link:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Not really used mapping before, when I tried to do this I got: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined, do I need another script? If so can I get it via Nuget?

Comment: @user1166905: The link that I sent you already has download link.

Comment: I found a Knockout.Mapping NuGet package which has gotten round this issue, but now I cannot get the values anymore, i.e. data-bind="value: selectedClient().Name" which worked before and says that Name doesn't exist for selectedClient when I try and get it in js

Comment: I had to change to: ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this); to get value binding working.

Out of interest if I want to post this value back how can I get it without all the extra mapping properties knockout applies?

EDIT: It's ok I found it: var unmapped = ko.toJSON(model.selectedClient());

Comment: @user1166905: Glad you found it :)